# Toggle a Div with Button changing margin-left property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div class="lateral-menu">` and a button

`<img class="responsive-icon" src="images/resposive-icon.svg"/>`

, the div is 220px wide and auto for the height.

The idea is to toggle one of the css properties of the lateral-menu while clicking the .resposive-icon

Seems to be that my code is not working, can someone orient me?

HTML

```
<div class="lateral-menu">
<img class="responsive-icon" src="images/resposive-icon.svg"/>
```

CSS

```
.lateral-menu {
height: auto;
background-color: #262525;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
width: 220px;
margin-left:-220px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.responsive-icon').click(function () {
$(".lateral-menu").animate({
    marginLeft: '0px'
}, 500);
});
```

I'm trying to toggle the margin-left from -220px to 0 to allow it to appear from the left side. Some suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly..see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey96a40y/)...any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Take a look on this example, it might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/07dmh3gL/2/

Comment: or is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ey96a40y/1/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: As you are already making the element as `absolute` positioned it is more appropriate to change the `left` property instead of `margin-left`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code sample you pasted that cause it to not work without some changes, but overall there isn't anything wrong with the approach.

If the HTML is meant to be like this:

```
<div class="lateral-menu"></div>
<img class="responsive-icon" src="images/resposive-icon.svg"/>
```

Then you need to apply a height to this example, as in [Lai's 2nd jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey96a40y/1/).

If the HTML is meant to be like this:

```
<div class="lateral-menu">
  <img class="responsive-icon" src="images/resposive-icon.svg"/>
</div>
```

Then it should be working just fine assuming you have jQuery loaded on the page. I recommend opening the [browser console to check for errors or warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#errors-and-warnings).

Also, you may find better luck using `left` since it's absolutely positioned like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/okohrvoL/1/

**Edit:**

To make the menu collapse again, you can add a simple check in the callback function:

```
$('.responsive-icon').click(function () {
  var targetValue;

  if ($('.lateral-menu').css('left') == "0px") {
    targetValue = '-220px';
  } else {
    targetValue = '0px';
  }

  $(".lateral-menu").animate({
    left: targetValue
  }, 500);
});
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/okohrvoL/2/

Comment: thanks! that part is working, what I'm trying to do is, when I click again the same button, to restore it to the original position. so far I can just show the lateral-menu

Comment: I've updated the answer with a simple way to close the menu on the next click.

Comment: Awesome @JeremyBaker now I understand how it works! thanks pal!